# Read ASP.Net Cookie from Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I'm having some trouble reading the ASP.NET cookie from a Classic ASP file.  Here is the code i'm using:

First off, I have the ASP.NET site setup in IIS. I setup an Application in the ASP.NET site and directed it to another folder in inetpub. This Application is called '/classicasp' because its all classic asp inside that application.

In the .aspx file, it is executing this code:

```
Response.Cookies["testcookie"].Path = "/classicasp";
Response.Cookies["testcookie"].Value = "test";
```

In the .asp file, it is executing this code:

```
<%
  for each cookie in Request.Cookies
     Response.Write( cookie & "=" & Request.Cookies(cookie) & "Path:" &
      "<br>")
  next
%>
```

But the .asp page is empty, there are no results displayed on the page from this For Next statement.. Any help on why this is happening?  I think i followed instructions and am doing this how its supposed to be, but i guess not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
dim x,y
for each x in Request.Cookies
  response.write("<p>")
  if Request.Cookies(x).HasKeys then
    for each y in Request.Cookies(x)
      response.write(x & ":" & y & "=" & Request.Cookies(x)(y))
      response.write("<br />")
    next
  else
    Response.Write(x & "=" & Request.Cookies(x) & "<br />")
  end if
  response.write "</p>"
next
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:
[Updating ASP cookie from ASP.NET (vice versa)](http://ryangaraygay.com/blog/post/Updating-ASP-cookie-from-ASPNET-vice-versa.aspx)