# How to integrate owin with classic asp project

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, owin, setcookie, owin-middleware

I have updated classic asp project to .net 4.8 version without restructuring or any code changes and added owin integration for the same. but I am not able  to set cookies for the project. I am getting HTTP/1.1 New Application Failed after owin redirection.
I want set some cookies in startup.cs which were used previosly for the project.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    
    var diConfig = new UnityDependencyInjectionConfigurator(container);

    app.UseInbuildIamOidc(diConfig, diConfig.CreateLazyLoadDependencyResolverBuilder());
}
//UseInbuildIamOidc is method created in common nuget
```

Comment: its old classic asp code with vbscript in it i just added startup.cs for owin integration and redirect. so far the owin integration works fine but i m not able to set cookies

Comment: Might be relevant - [Read ASP.Net Cookie from Classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7278668)

Comment: This suggestion should work for you^  But if somehow it doesn't your issue is probably related to the Application Pools, where ASP Classic uses NON MANAGED and .NET is Managed Application Pool .   For example if you tried to run ASP CLASSIC with a Managed Application Pool it would lose the session randomly likely.

Comment: @easleyfixed Classic ASP can run in a Managed Application Pool, the session timeout is driven by the Application Pool recycle schedule and other factors like CPU, memory constraints etc., which are all configurable in the Application Pool Advanced Settings.

Comment: I'm not talking about the timeout, I'm talking about the whole session going MIA for no reason, a user is fine then goes to another page or refreshes and they get logged out for no reason.   My point was, make sure you select the correct type of application pool for your environment.  And the reason I worded the previous statement as "randomly" in there, because sometimes it would stay for several minutes, other times the session is just gone for no reason regardless of hours left of timeout etc.

Comment: @easleyfixed It's not random but yes it's not limited to "timeouts". The recycle settings for an application pool are very clear; specific times, request limits, private memory limit, regular time interval, virtual memory limit and disable recycling for configuration changes. So yes, not purely "timeouts".

Comment: Yes those are all intended settings, I'm talking about situations where the session for no configuration reason other than trying to use asp classic code in a managed .net situation often provides unpredictable results including loss of session well before designed timeout is reached.